# JPA connect to Derby Database with Hibernate-ORM related problem in Quarkus

Tags: java, spring, jpa, derby, quarkus-hibernate-orm

Currently, I am trying to build an API with JPA and Derby Database, and I've got some problems with Hibernate Reactive/Hibernate ORM.

Particularly, I want to connect to a Derby database server as follows:

QueryService.java:

```
@Transactional
@RequestScoped
public class QueryService implements Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
    public QueryService() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        String urlDB = "my-persistence-unit";
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(urlDB);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        emf.close();
    }
```

application.properties:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=derby
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/appDB;create=true
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
quarkus.datasource.username=admin
quarkus.datasource.password=admin

quarkus.live-reload.instrumentation=true
```

In the persistence.xml file, I define a persistence unit to be used by the EntityManagerFactory in QueryService.java.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

    <persistence-unit
            name="my-persistence-unit"
            transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/appDB;create=true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If I run this, I get this error: `{ "details": "Error id 07333181-bf2e-4640-8497-01de9bf6ccf7-1, java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.recording.RecordedState.isReactive()\" because \"recordedState\" is null", "stack": "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.recording.RecordedState.isReactive()\" because \"recordedState\" is null\r\n\tat io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:172)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)\r\n\tat javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)\r\n\tat javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)\r\n\tat app.QueryService.init(QueryService.java:29)\r\n\tat app.QueryService_Bean.create(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat app.QueryService_Bean.create(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.RequestContext.getIfActive(RequestContext.java:74)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getDelegate(ClientProxies.java:30)\r\n\tat app.QueryService_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat app.QueryService_ClientProxy.obtainCourseList(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat app.Scolarite.obtainCourseList(Scolarite.java:49)\r\n\tat app.Scolarite_Subclass.obtainCourseList$$superforward1(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat app.Scolarite_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:133)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:104)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:38)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:58)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:33)\r\n\tat app.Scolarite_Subclass.obtainCourseList(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat app.Scolarite_ClientProxy.obtainCourseList(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat app.ScolariteApplication.getCourseList(ScolariteApplication.java:22)\r\n\tat app.ScolariteApplication$quarkusrestinvoker$getCourseList_9c2e0d4fdac50820476d652c171e60223f72a1d5.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:114)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)\r\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)\r\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)\r\n\tat org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)\r\n\tat org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)" }`

I tried to search for this on the internet, and it is said that this was because Hibernate Reactive and Hibernate Orm cannot be used together. But I don't know how to solve it. I am quite new to this. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @vanje Hi, I have edited the error with full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is happening because Quarkus is still using the FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider. But you want the HibernatePersistenceProvider.
In my code I had to create this provider explicitly. So instead of Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory
try:

```
var persistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(urlDB);
```